# JPopUpMenu problem with adding menu items

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating JPopUpMenu with following code:

```
JPopupMenu popup1 = new JPopupMenu();
JPopupMenu popup2 = new JPopupMenu();

JMenuItem freeze = new JMenuItem("freeze");
freeze.addActionListener(new FreezActionListener(this));

JMenuItem unfreeze = new JMenuItem("unfreeze");
unfreeze.addActionListener(new UnFreezActionListener(this));

JMenuItem sortU = new JMenuItem("sort");
JMenuItem sortD = new JMenuItem("sort");



popup1.add(freeze);
popup1.add(unfreeze);
popup1.add(sortU);

popup2.add(freeze);
popup2.add(unfreeze);
popup2.add(sortD);
```

After executing this code,  `popup2` menu works fine but `popup1` has only `sortU` item.
If I add menu items first to `popup2` and then to `popup1`,  then `popup1` works fine and `popup2` doesn't.

Is it normal behavior or did I miss something ?
I've searched about this but can't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JMenuItem` belongs to one, and only one, `JPopupMenu` (or any other menu).  You cannot add a Swing component to more than one container; if you do, then the component will automatically be removed from the previous container.  So when you add `freeze` and `unfreeze` to `popup2`, they are being automatically removed from `popup1`.

What you need to do to make this work properly is to create a total of six `JMenuItem`s, three for each menu.  The fact that two pairs of menu items do the same thing is only reflected in that the `ActionListener` does the same thing for each.  So....

```
JPopupMenu popup1 = new JPopupMenu();
JPopupMenu popup2 = new JPopupMenu();

FreezActionListener freezer = new FreezActionListener(this);

JMenuItem freeze1 = new JMenuItem("freeze");
freeze1.addActionListener(freezer);
JMenuItem freeze2 = new JMenuItem("freeze");
freeze2.addActionListener(freezer);

UnFreezActionListener unfreezer = new UnFreezActionListener(this);

JMenuItem unfreeze1 = new JMenuItem("unfreeze");
unfreeze1.addActionListener(unfreezer);
JMenuItem unfreeze2 = new JMenuItem("unfreeze");
unfreeze2.addActionListener(unfreezer);

JMenuItem sortU = new JMenuItem("sort");
JMenuItem sortD = new JMenuItem("sort");



popup1.add(freeze1);
popup1.add(unfreeze1);
popup1.add(sortU);

popup2.add(freeze2);
popup2.add(unfreeze2);
popup2.add(sortD);
```

Comment: There is no need to create multiple listeners. Listeners, unlike components, can be shared.

Comment: That's what happens when I hastily copy and paste code...thanks for the comment.  I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the better solution is to create Actions. Actions can be shared and added to multiple components (JMenuItems, JButtons etc). You can even enable/disable the Action which will enable/disable all the components at the same time.

You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information.

Comment: I know it's years after this was posted, but I stumbled upon it trying to satisfy my curiosity and wanted to say that while your answer was lacking on details and an example of implementation, I think it *could* be a "more correct" answer, although the accepted answer works as well.